# git push heroku master - Fetching repository, done. Everything up-to-date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, deployment, github

Note: I am using iOS Mavericks.
I have been using RailsApp Project Tutorials.

It says that everything is working ok:

```
MacBook-Air:XXX zachmachuca$ git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Everything up-to-date
```

But when I enter `$ heroku open` the page shows me:

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the
>   address or the page may have moved.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'

gem 'rails', '4.1.5'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development,:test do
gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:  
https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read
 more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

There is no clear error message that I can find.

Comment: This is the default Rails 404 page, and by the sounds of it, the problem is in your `routes.rb`. You need to [define a root route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root).

Comment: Thanks for your help fivedigit. I am trying to use the link you gave me and I really don't know where to begin. It says `root to: 'pages#main' root 'pages#main' # shortcut for the above`. So am I supposed to enter it as is? I am being cautious because I don't want to dig my hole deeper.

Comment: Can you post your `config/routes.rb` file?